# Getting a null value on my arraylist.set(). using jsp

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, null, set

My objective is to add words from a html form, store them in my array, display them in the page, and have two links one for delete the item and one for edit the item(the word for edit will be entered in another html form).

I am using an arrayList to store the input coming from an Input type. I am able to add and delete my item, but when I tried to change the value of an item in my arrayList (I am using arrayList.set()), my value returns null. If I hard code the set() I see my item change but for some reason I can't get the value from my input type. Wondering what I am missing.

I have two jsp pages. main.jsp and edit.jsp.
One java class WordOperations with all the validations

Here is my code Sorry if it is messy and if doesn't display right in here. This is the first time I am posting on stackoverflow

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

This is my code for the form where i display my items main.jsp

```
 <h3>Word List</h3>
        <form action="WordOperations" method="POST">
            Word: <input type="text" name="newWord">
            <input type="submit" value="Add">
        </form>
        <br/>

            <%
                ArrayList<String> words = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("words");

                if (words!=null)
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
                    {
                         out.println("<p>" +  "<a href='http://www."+ words.get(i) +".com'>" + words.get(i) +"</a>"  + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='WordOperations?delete=" + i + "'>Delete</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='WordOperations?edit=" + i + "'>Edit</a></p>");

                    }
                }

            %>
```

This is my code for my for where I enter the new information edit.jsp

```
  <form action="WordOperations?" method="POST">
        New Link:<input type="text" name="userChange">
        <input type="submit" name="userChangePassword" value="Change link">
        </form>
```

And this is the code for validation of my forms WordOperations.java

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession();

        String newWord = request.getParameter("newWord");
        String delete = request.getParameter("delete");
        String edit = request.getParameter("edit");
        String newLink = request.getParameter("userChange");

        if (delete!=null) //delete a word
        {
            int delIndex = Integer.parseInt(delete);

            ArrayList<String> words = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("words");
            words.remove(delIndex);

            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/main.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("message", "Word deleted");
            rd.forward(request, response);  
        }
        else if(edit !=null)
        {   


            int edIndex = Integer.parseInt(edit);
            String link = newLink;
            ArrayList<String> words = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("words");
            words.set(edIndex,"google");
            words.add(newLink);
                         RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/edit.jsp");


            request.setAttribute("message", "Word edited");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }
        else //logging in
        {
            if (newWord!=null && !newWord.equals(""))
            {
                ArrayList<String> words = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("words");

                words.add(newWord);              

                RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/main.jsp");
                request.setAttribute("message", "Word added");
                rd.forward(request, response);

            }
            else
            {
                RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/main.jsp");
                request.setAttribute("message", "Word is required");
                rd.forward(request, response);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It is a bit hard guessing exactly what happens here. You could improve your question by supplying the stack trace that happens and by pointing out on which line in the code to problem is located. From a first glance I would say that you retrieve the `ArrayList` from the session here `ArrayList<String> words = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("words");` and I further guess that the session does not contain an attribute `words` therefore the array is null and causes an NullPointerException when you are trying to access it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a logical mistake ..

You are running servlet `WordOperations.java` **twice** in editing the word and passing `edit` parameter once and passing `userChange` parameter in another and **NOT** together which would solve the problem.

Here is the mistake.

But first set the Arraylist `words` in session on adding of first word. You can do like this:

```
else //logging in
            {
                if (newWord != null && !newWord.equals("")) {
                    ArrayList<String> words = (ArrayList<String>) s.getAttribute("words");
                    if (words == null) {
                        words = new ArrayList<>();
                        words.add(newWord);
                        s.setAttribute("words", words);
                    } else {
                        words.add(newWord);
                    }

                    RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/main.jsp");
                    request.setAttribute("message", "Word added");
                    rd.forward(request, response);

                }
```

Now Here is the mistake :

When the `Arraylist` `words` is listed down in `main.jsp`. It contains

> word Delete_link Edit_link

Now Delete_link > `<a href='WordOperations?delete=" + i + "'>Delete</a>` is working fine because you are just redirecting it to `WordsOperations.java` with parameter `delete = i` and deleting the word from ArrayList.

WordsOperations.java

```
String delete = request.getParameter("delete");

 if (delete!=null) //delete a word
        {
            int delIndex = Integer.parseInt(delete);

            ArrayList<String> words = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("words");
            words.remove(delIndex);

            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/main.jsp");
            request.setAttribute("message", "Word deleted");
            rd.forward(request, response);  
        }
```

**BUT**

In Edit_link > `<a href='WordOperations?edit=" + i + "'>Edit</a>` You are calling servlet `WordsOperations.java` with just parameter `edit = i` and **NOT** passing `userChange` parameter with it.

Thus `newLink` is **NULL** on

`String newLink = request.getParameter("userChange");`

SO the code in `WordsOperation.java` i.e

```
else if(edit !=null)
        {   


            int edIndex = Integer.parseInt(edit);
            String link = newLink;
            ArrayList<String> words = (ArrayList<String>) session.getAttribute("words");
            words.set(edIndex,"google");
            words.add(newLink);
                         RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/edit.jsp");


            request.setAttribute("message", "Word edited");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }
```

Will get executed as `edit!=null` is `true`. But it will add `newLink` in Arraylist `words` which happens to be NULL. Hence null is getting added to your list.

There is no problem with `Arraylist.set()` method.

Now in the above code you are calling `edit.jsp` after adding `newLink`. 
But when `WordsOperation.java` gets called from `edit.jsp` form, it is just passing userChange parameter and **NOT** `edit` parameter which is needed to be there to execute the `else if(edit!=null)` block of servlet `WordsOperations.java`.

```
<form action="WordOperations?" method="POST">
            New Link:<input type="text" name="userChange">
            <input type="submit" name="userChangePassword" value="Change link">
        </form>
```

Rest is on you. Just take care you pass edit and UserChange parameter both to Servlet WordsOperations.java to get your work done.

Suggestion: Pass `edit` parameter to `edit.jsp` and then pass `edit and UserChange` parameter to `WordsOperation.java`.

Hope it helps.